# Is there a way to make a mounted gvfs volume shortcut on the desktop or home folder?

Tags: drive, gvfs

I have a network drive and I want to make it accessible to apps , such as LiberOffice.
I cannot make a link. The drive is available under .gvfs. Is there a way to have it as a link in my desktop or home folder?

Answer (score 2):

I just created a symbolic link for the directory I wanted in my home folder, and used Nautilus to "Create Link" and then placed that on my desktop. Worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command in the terminal:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

Then select 'Location' for Type and paste your full gvfs location. SMB locations are allowed as well.

If you receive an error when trying to run the command, you probably need to install gnome-panel:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

For whatever reason, I'm *not* able to make a launcher to create launchers. :(

IMHO, it is kind of absurd that we need to go to this much effort just to create a gvfs or network link. Why can't we just drag and drop like Windows? As it is, it just attempts to create a link that will *never* work, what's the point of that?